# Strange AJAX HTTP error, 302 redirect error after update and migration

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a Drupal 7 site (ver 7.67) running on CloudWays, PHP 7.1, MySQL 5.5.

I get the AJAX error "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 302"
The debugging information is limited:

"Path: /admin/structure/views/some_view/preview/block/ajax"

This happens on editing any View (Views 7.x-3.23) or when creating content with any autocomplete field.

Seems like it should be something simple, that something wasn't migrated correctly and pointing not right.

I have looked through the server logs and the php logs and can't find anything to do with a redirect error other than the AJAX error.

Where do I look to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you disable "Auto Preview" in Views, does the error go away? Are the autocomplete fields for a vocab with redirects for URLs when the term is missing? You might find a clue by using Chrome's Inspect tool. Go to the "Network" tab and refresh a page with the error. The ajax call that results in the error will be in the list, and its "type" is probably "xhr". Look at the Headers (particularly the Request URL and its query parameters), Preview, and Response tabs to see if you can narrow down where the problem is coming from.

Comment: The error goes away when I disable "Auto Preview". I used Chrome's inspect tool, the referer: https://dsomedrupalsite/admin/structure/views/view/some_view/edit/block?destination=node/4951
There is nothing in the Preview or response. Did find the Referrer Policy: No-referrer-when-downgrade
Not sure what was downgraded.

Comment: Could not edit comment after 5 min.
The error goes away when I disable "Auto Preview". I used Chrome's inspect tool, the referer: https://somedrupalsite/admin/structure/views/view/some_view/edit/block?destination=node/4951
Did find the Referrer Policy: No-referrer-when-downgrade
Not sure what was downgraded.
In an insert prepend method, the generated js that's loaded after css has a warning when I put the url in the browser, "trying to load a script from unauthenticated sources" But there are not any references (other than basePath) in the js.  
Would that cause an issue?

Comment: `trying to load a script from unauthenticated sources` usually means that the page you are on is encrypted (https), but the address of the script isn't (http). This would also cause the request's Referrer Policy to be set to `No-referrer-when-downgraded`. Can you tell what module/process is responsible for the unsecured script? You can use the fact that the error is triggered by previewing the view to your advantage. Recreate the view one step at a time, clicking `Update preview` at each step until the error happens. Then, open the inspector's Network tab and click `Update preview` once more.

Comment: I just updated Drupal 7 core from 7.67 to 7.68 and resolved the issue. Looks like the big push was to make Drupal 7 core compatible with PHP 7.3. I am running PHP 7.1. 
Thank you for your help! I truly appreciate your time, experience, patience, and wisdom. Again, thank you.